# Designing architecture for an MVC5 Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm making an MVC website. Here's what I've planned to do earlier:

```
Data Access Layer
     ^
     |
Business Layer
     ^
     |
Web API 2    <-- Apps or whatever
     ^
     |
MVC5 Website
```

But I think the following would be a better idea, because since the website and the WebAPI are going to be on the same server in my case, I thought it would make no sense for the website to parse the JSON response of the API.

```
Data Access Layer
     ^
     |
Business Layer   <--   Web API    <-- Apps or whatever
     ^
     |
MVC5 Website
```

I am completely new to Web APIs (never done WebAPI or WCF before) and I don't really know what approach to take.

So here are my questions
1. I need a chart (like the ones I've made) representing a better solution with explanation
2. A Project structure for the Visual Studio **2013** Solution that you would recommend

*Please note that I have planned to use VS2013's new ASP.NET App project template - not the VS2012 type web templates. Answer keeping this in mind.*

**A better and descriptive answer is most welcome**

Comment: Hi, I believe you can help me with this issue if you have 30 secs... Thks a lot! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401403/add-web-api-to-an-existing-mvc-5-web-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO definitely do the second, not the first.  There is no value having an MVC website call your own Web API.

Comment: Thanks I'll consider the second, can you make an edit about the VS project templates to use (for MVC and WebAPI)

Comment: @gldraphael You probably won't like my answer.  Templates are a crutch.  I don't use them.

Comment: okay so what would you suggest I should do. I just want each layer to be in a different project. How should I go about? I just need help with setting up the projects, I'll be able to figure stuff out after that

Comment: It's been 4 years and I'm all "Darrel answered my question" right now!

Answer (score 2):

To me, this depends on the scope of your application. I've seen a larger corporate system use both an MVC instance alongside a WebAPI with the WebAPI used exclusively for CRUD operations sent as ajax calls from the UI (View's) returned by MVC in a Model-View-ViewModel pattern.

The WebAPI was also consumed by other intranet systems.

So it looked something like this:

```
MVC  OTHER INTRANET
 |     |
 / \   /
|   \ /
|  WebAPI
|    |
 \  /
  \/
Business
 Layer
   |
   |
Data Access
   |
   DB
```

This same company also had a separate WebAPI attached to a DAL used as of a home-grown cross company workflow system. As each organizational unit within the company had the same data (domain) model defined, they would physically move (a.k.a SELECT/DELETE from groupA.db.active, INSERT to groupB.db.active, INSERT to groupA.db.INactive with an updated step ID. It worked just fine but I doubt it was the best performing system.

Hope this helps.